# How to navigate through CardItem with react-navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

Hi I have simple post list and want to navigate through each post into the their pages. I am using react-navigation but it seems not working inside CardItem. How can I solve it? Here is the code.Also all configurations are done perfectly inside MainNavigator.

```
 <Card>


       <CardItem>
              <Left>
                <Thumbnail source={{uri: 'Image URL'}} />
                <Body>
                  <Text>NativeBase</Text>
                  <Text note>GeekyAnts</Text>
                </Body>
              </Left>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem cardBody
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('post')}
>
              <Image source={{uri: 'Image URL'}} style={{height: 200, width: null, flex: 1}}/>
            </CardItem>
            <CardItem>
              <Left>
                <Button transparent>
                  <Icon active name="thumbs-up" />
                  <Text>12 Likes</Text>
                </Button>
              </Left>
              <Body>
                <Button transparent>
                  <Icon active name="chatbubbles" />
                  <Text>4 Comments</Text>
                </Button>
              </Body>
              <Right>
                <Text>11h ago</Text>
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
```

Its not showing any error just when you click it doesn't navigate.

Comment: Are you providing `navigation` in who renders the `Card`?

Comment: It will be good , if share your  error also so that we get exact problem.

Comment: it doesn't show any error message just not navigating

Answer (score 0):

you can do this if you want to navigate to particular page on click of the card

```
<Container>
 <Content>
   <TouchableHighlight onPress=(()=>{console.log('navigate)})>
      **In Between you can render you card**
      <Card/>
   </TouchableHighlight>
 </Content>
</Container>
```

May be this can help you with

Comment: It throws error undefined is not an object this.props.navigation.navigate. Here is the line that I used. 
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Post")}>

Comment: onPress=(()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate("Post")}

Comment: it's still not working. This time syntax error in this line.

Comment: ) is missing at the last of the comment so I have corrected that one below
onPress=(()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate("Post")})

Comment: still the same error in the same line. It seems something wrong with this approach.